# How to input forward slash to the array shell

Tags: linux, shell, dirname

I want to separate the text from each other with forwardslash and in console nothing appears with this code (I also tried to make variable sep="/" which I put behind the ${arr[i]})

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$1
  
IFS='/'

read -ra arr <<< $path

#echo ${#arr[@]}

function dirname(){
    array=()
    for (( i = 0; i <= $((${#arr[@]} - 2)); i ++ )) 
    do
        array+="${arr[i]}"
        array+="/"
    done
    echo $array
}
```

and this input

```
./ukol5.sh /c/Users/Michal/Desktop
```

I got this output

```
c Users Michal
```

Comment: `echo $array` is equivalent to `echo ${array[0]}`. If you want to echo the whole array, it's `echo "${array[@]}"`

Comment: To append to an array it's `array+=("${array[i]}")` -- you need the parentheses.

Comment: Read a bash array tutorial to get all the details right.

Comment: array+=("${array[i]}") --> not true, this isnt working the functional is array+="${arr[i]}"

Comment: Only what I asked is how to push to the array the forward slash

Comment: It's the same: `array+=("/")`

Comment: You're not seeing the `/` in the output because you didn't quote the variable, so `/` is still acting as a word delimiter because of `IFS`.

Comment: Did you read my last comment? If you don't quote the variable, `IFS='/'` makes it split the variable at `/` characters, so you don't see them in the output.